# How can I prove that binary multiplication decision problem is solved in O(logn) space?

Tags: proof-verification, computational-complexity, turing-machines

I can prove this if I use a NTM Turing Machine, but it is required to use a two-taped DTM, while taking into account only the space of the second "work tape"

Comment: Can you provide an outline of how you would handle this using the NTM and where you get stuck moving to the DTM?  Questions with context and shown-working tend to be better received and answered.

Comment: When you say "NTM Turing Machine", does that mean "Non-deterministic Turing Machine Turing Machine"?

Comment: Refer to the section titled 'Optimizing Space Complexity' in the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm.